# Google Cloud SQL : Change to second generation possible?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have a working system using the Google App Engine including a Cloud SQL Database instance of the first generation. Is it possible to switch the database instance to the second generation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On top of the previous answer, you can facilitate the Export/Import functions available by default to transfer the data.
Note that a lot of work is required to the code if you transfer to the second generation.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to change the type of an existing instance, a new instance must be created.